# PHP preg_match will not allow æøå

Tags: php, validation, utf-8

I am trying to make my registration script accept only letters and æøå, but nothing I've tried so far has worked. It still won't accept æøå.

This is my code so far

```
if ($_POST['first'] != "" && preg_match("%^[-a-zA-Z æøå\/]+$%", $_POST['first']) == true && strlen($_POST['first']) > 0) { 
    $input_first = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['first']); } 
else { header("Location: ../register.php?n=2"); exit; die(); }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works here, https://eval.in/716341. Do the `æøå` arrive to the server as those characters? You don't need all those checks. Because of the `+` in the regex you know that there is a value so it won't be empty and the length will be > 1.

Comment: If your pattern and your string are UTF-8 encoded, you need to set [the `u` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php). Note that your tests are redundant `!= ""` and `strlen > 0` are the same and your regex forbids an empty value because of your `+` quantifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your PHP file is already UTF-8 encoded, you should tell your database, that you need UTF-8. Instead of fiddling with the configurations of MySQL, just tell your connection object, which character-set you expect, the database does the rest for you.

This is an example for a mysqli connection object:

```
 //Test-ak
  $db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPw, $dbName);
  $db->set_charset("utf8");
```

Afterwards your queries will return UTF-8 encoded results.